Is it possible to change your island's name?
I gave a name to the island on my Nintendo profile save file.
Someone else played the game on their Nintendo profile, but the island and the island’s name were the exact same. Essentially, we were sharing the same save file.
Is there a way to change the island’s name? A way to do it without having to wipe the island would be preferable, but not required.

No.
Once created, island names, character names and birthdays cannot be changed. There is a giant warning that tells you this when you first start the game.
Saves for Animal Crossing: New Horizons work differently to saves for other Switch games. Only one island can be created per Switch console, and once created 8 total player characters (separated by profiles on the console) can live on that island.
The only way you can change your island name is to delete your save from the console, and start from scratch. Consider transferring any items you want to keep to a friend's island temporarily before doing this.
